# Soundcloud HTML5 Widget CSS Error on @media (max-width: 350px) and (min-height: 166px)

Tags: html, widget, soundcloud

On "@media (max-width: 350px) and (min-height: 166px)" the div with class "sound_*art sc-border-box sound*_artLeft" is hidden, but the position of the div with class "sound_*content sound*_contentRight" isn't correct. The position "left: 165px" should be "left: 0px".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in a couple of minutes. Sorry for inconvenience.